# Have I found a proof that i = 0?

Tags: complex-numbers

Euler's formula states that: $$e^{iθ} = cos(θ) + i*sin(θ)$$ Plugging in 2π for theta gives 1, but so does plugging in 0 for theta. Therefore: $$e^0 = e^{2iπ}$$ Taking the natural logarithm of both sides gives: $$ 0 = 2πi$$ Dividing both sides by 2pi yields:
$$0 = i$$.

Clearly, I have a mistake somewhere, but I don't know where. Am I misusing Euler's formula or is it something else? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Don't worry, you just need more experience working with complex numbers.  Your problem is the step "Taking the natural logarithm of both sides".

Comment: BTW, $1^2 = (-1)^2$, but $1 \ne -1$ exhibits a similar phenomenon.

Comment: Log in complex analysis is very weird and includes a branch (i.e. it’s discontinuous).  I think the issue happened when you took the log of exp(i 2 pi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well problem is if $f(B)=f(A)$ ($f$ is a function), that does not always mean
that $B=A$.
For example
$\sin(0)=\sin(2\pi)$;
that doesn't mean that $0=2\pi$.
In real numbers when
$e^A=e^B$ ($A$ and $B$ are real numbers),
we can say that $A=B$,
but that is not always true for complex numbers.

Comment: Please abstain from answering questions which have been posted before.